# Reference Counting ,ARC

Tags: objective-c, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Does the objects get deallocated instantly when the reference count goes to 0 or wait till encountering the release method (inserted automatically by compiler in ARC) explicitly for dealloc to happen ?

Comment: It takes calls to `release` for the reference count to get to 0.

Comment: It's a mistake to think the reference count ever goes to zero.  The current implementation of the runtime will call `dealloc` when the count _would go to zero_, but never actually decrements it to zero.  This is effectively the same, but can be confusing if you're poking around and trying to understand the underlying behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole issue with memory management is that it's difficult to make large programs where there's only a single, obvious place to free an object. If this were the case, there would be no need for reference counting at all!

The compiler inserts `retain` and `release` calls whenever references are made or destroyed. When `release` is called, the reference count is decremented. If in doing so the count reaches 0, `deinit` is called, and the object's memory is freed. This is all part of the `release` call.